# Flash music player stop working when I embed it into my index page

Tags: flash, audio-player

Inside my /test folder/music_player/ have have a file called mini_player.swf. If I play it without embedding it anywhere, like this: http://ada.kiexpro.com/test/music_player/player_mini.swf
everything is OK. But when I add it into my index page: http://ada.kiexpro.com/test/ the song doesn't start.

I'm using a song_list.xml like this:

```
<songs>



 <song>

  <track>She can dance too</track>

  <artist>Artist One</artist>

  <url>songs/song.mp3</url>

 </song>
```

(continues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the song path to the real path to the mp3 file. For example: `http://ada.kiexpro.com/test/songs/song.mp3`